# Visual Studio Code extension to emulate LinqPad

Tags: c#, data-visualization, programming

I'm a frequent user of LinqPad primarily for it's handy `Dump` extension method. With recent changes to C# which means far less boilerplate code, I thought that maybe I could replace LinqPad with VSC with the help of an extension.

Crucial features that are required are:

1. Ability to dump anything to a pane for viewing (text, images)
2. Ability to provide simple UIs to perform an action. An example use case is showing an image and the giving the user (me) an option to delete it.
3. Ability to include references to other .NET DLLs.
4. Full compatibility with the latest release of .NET.
5. Save the above, ideally in a single file

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are (were) looking for. I was looking as I cannot afford to upgrade my version of linqpad anymore but I have not used this yet.

Sharppad - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmazouri.sharppad

Edit: also just came across this.. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-interactive-preview-3-vs-code-insiders-and-polyglot-notebooks/

Answer (score 0):

As @kas mentioned, the Polyglot noetbook is officially available now.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-polyglot-notebooks-harness-the-power-of-multilanguage-notebooks-in-visual-studio-code/

VSC market:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am looking into Polyglot as well.  So far it feels really awkward to used, as opposed to LinqPad, where I can practically write full programs.  Any advice on how best to use it?  I really only need C#, the poly part is irrelevant to me.